# Issue using Knockout if / ifnot without a container element

Tags: knockout.js

I have something similar to the following html:

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: items, afterRender: alternateRowColor }">
    <!-- ko if: isNew() -->
    <tr>
      <td><input data-bind="text: prop"/></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: !isNew() -->
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: prop"/></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With a collection of objects which are defined as follows:

```
function NewItem() {
  this.prop = ko.observable(0);
  this.isNew = ko.observable(true);
}

function Item(prop) {
  this.prop = prop;
  this.isNew = ko.observable(false);
}
```

The "Items" are from the server and the "NewItems" are added when a user clicks a link. The idea is simply to have an input box for new items, but just a display for existing items. This seems to work fine for existing items (when isNew is false), but when isNew is true, both sets of markup render (two rows are added, one editable followed by one display only). I would expect only the first "tr" to render if isNew is true. Does anyone know what is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

My [Switch-Case binding](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case) is meant for solving this kind of problem.

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: items, afterRender: alternateRowColor }">
    <tr data-bind="switch: true">
      <!-- ko case: isNew -->
        <td><input data-bind="text: prop"/></td>
      <!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko case: $else -->
        <td data-bind="text: prop"/></td>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I actually tried using your library as well, but wasn't aware of the "$else" syntax. I like this solution (and your library), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `ifnot` instead of the `!` sign. Remove the `()`, you are evaluating it's value.

```
<!-- ko ifnot: isNew -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this using a template selector. I've created a fiddle which demonstrates the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/tltjr/3FUQR/

I'm still not sure why the `if` behavior wasn't working, but I feel like this approach is more flexible and more readable anyway.